# How to prevent re-render of other TextInputs in a form when changing state of a single TextInput?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have two `reusable` TextInputs, namely, `AppTextInput` and a reusable button, namely, `AppButton`.

Here are their codes:

`AppButton.js`

```
const AppButton = ({
    title = '',
    iconName = '',
    onPress,
    mode = 'contained',
    ...props
}) => {

    console.log("Button rendered")

    return (
        <Button
            icon={iconName}
            mode={mode}
            onPress={onPress}
            {...props}
        >
            {title}
        </Button>
    )
}
```

Here is for the `AppTextInput.js`

```
const AppTextInput = ({
    inputStyle,
    outlineStyle,
    leftIcon = '',
    rightIcon = '',
    right,
    onRightIconPress,
    label = '',
    ...props
}) => {

    console.log([label, " TextInput Rendered"])

    return (
        <TextInput
            label={label}
            mode='outlined'
            style={[styles.inputStyle, inputStyle]}
            outlineStyle={[styles.outlineStyle, outlineStyle]}
            left={
                leftIcon ? (
                    <TextInput.Icon
                        icon={leftIcon}
                        disabled
                    />
                ) : null
            }
            right={
                rightIcon ? (
                    <TextInput.Icon
                        icon={rightIcon}
                        onPress={onRightIconPress}
                    />
                ) : (
                    right
                )
            }
            {...props}
        />
    )
}
```

I added `console.log()`s on the two to determine if they re-renders or not.

Now here's my problem:

I have a simple form that consists of fields of `CurrentPassword` and `NewPassword`.

Whenever I change the state for the `icon` of the `CurrentPassword` field, it also renders the `AppButton` and the `NewPassword` TextInput.

How do I prevent the re-render?

Below is sample image and code for the parent component:

[image]

`ChangePasswordScreen.js`

```
const ChangePasswordScreen = () => {

    const [currentPasswordSecureText, setCurrentPasswordSecureText] = useState(true);
    const [newPasswordSecureText, setNewPasswordSecureText] = useState(true);

    const [currentPasswordIcon, setCurrentPasswordIcon] = useState("eye-off-outline");
    const [newPasswordIcon, setNewPasswordIcon] = useState("eye-off-outline");

    const showHideCurrentPassword = () => {

        setCurrentPasswordSecureText(!currentPasswordSecureText)

        currentPasswordIcon === "eye-off-outline" ?
            setCurrentPasswordIcon("eye") :
            setCurrentPasswordIcon("eye-off-outline");
    }

    const showHideNewPassword = () => {
        setNewPasswordSecureText(!newPasswordSecureText)

        newPasswordIcon === "eye-off-outline" ?
            setNewPasswordIcon("eye") :
            setNewPasswordIcon("eye-off-outline");
    }

    return (
        <ScrollView
            style={styles.container}
            keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'
        >

            <AppTextInput
                label='Current Password'
                autoCapitalize="none"
                autoCorrect={false}
                inputStyle={styles.input}
                leftIcon='lock'
                rightIcon={currentPasswordIcon}
                secureTextEntry={currentPasswordSecureText}
                onRightIconPress={showHideCurrentPassword}
            />

            <AppTextInput
                label='New Password'
                autoCapitalize="none"
                autoCorrect={false}
                inputStyle={styles.input}
                leftIcon='lock'
                rightIcon={newPasswordIcon}
                secureTextEntry={newPasswordSecureText}
                onRightIconPress={showHideNewPassword}
            />

            <AppButton
                title="Update"
                style={styles.button}
            />

        </ScrollView>
    )
}
```

This is the result of the log whenever I press the `eye icon`.

[image]

I have tried `useCallback` and `useMemo` but I don't quite get it as I am still unfamiliar with the two.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
const name = useRef('');

<TextInput
    ref={name}
    onChangeText={text => (name.current.value = text)}
    placeholder={'Name'}
    placeholderTextColor="#909090"
    style={{width: '95%', height: '100%'}}
/>
```

Maybe this will solve your problem. Replace your useState with useRef for input.
Please let me know if this works.

Comment: When binding ref on the component, is not necessary handling `onChangeText` . You can remove that line

Answer (score 0):

That's very common issue in react development.

I have faced same issues earlier So, I tried below solution.

- create custom input component with internal state management and combine use of useImperativeHandle.
- only individual component state will and update and then it will re-rendered only.
- using the useImperativeHandle you can simply get the input value and set the input values with ref.

Example:

```
import {View} from 'native-base';
import React, {
  forwardRef,
  useState,
  useCallback,
  useRef,
  useImperativeHandle,
} from 'react';
import {TextInput, TextInputProps, Button, Keyboard} from 'react-native';

// ** Input component with managing state internally
const AppTextInput = forwardRef((props: TextInputProps, ref) => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(props?.defaultValue || '');

  const inputRef = useRef<TextInput>(null);

  const onChangeTextHandler = useCallback((enteredValue: string) => {
    setInputValue(enteredValue);
  }, []);

  const initHandler = useCallback(() => {
    return {
      getValue: () => inputValue,
      setValue: (newVal: string) => setInputValue(newVal),
      focus: () => inputRef.current?.focus?.(),
      blur: () => inputRef.current?.blur?.(),
    };
  }, [inputValue]);

  useImperativeHandle(ref, initHandler, [initHandler]);

  return (
    <TextInput
      ref={inputRef}
      keyboardType="default"
      blurOnSubmit={false}
      {...props}
      value={inputValue}
      onChangeText={onChangeTextHandler}
    />
  );
});

// ** Usage
const App = () => {
  const emailRef = useRef(null);
  const passwordRef = useRef(null);

  const loginHandler = useCallback(() => {
    const emailInputVal = emailRef.current?.getValue?.();
    const passwordInputVal = passwordRef.current?.getValue?.();
    console.log('email : ', emailInputVal, ' password : ', passwordInputVal);
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <AppTextInput
        ref={emailRef}
        onSubmitEditing={() => {
          passwordRef.current?.focus?.();
        }}
      />
      <AppTextInput
        ref={passwordRef}
        onSubmitEditing={() => {
          Keyboard.dismiss();
          loginHandler();
        }}
      />
      <Button title="Login" onPress={loginHandler} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you can run a line of code that shows you  `button rendering...`, there's a React core functionality called `the reconciliation algorithm`. This part works at low level DOM manipulation and it's responsible for determining  what DOM nodes are being rendered / updated. Basically it's a diff check between Virtual DOM and Real DOM.

EDIT:

As an addition to my previous comment where I try to explain in a very simple way how React works, I would say: Every change of state will trigger re-rendering. But React provide us some options to work around this issue. One of them is working with `useRef` hook.